# Bidirectional direct communication from server to app without Push Notification

Tags: android, ios, mobile, backend

I have an mobile application (iOS and Android) and I need send some notification from my server to these, then the mobile app need to make some tasks and when they finish, send a message from mobile to server to confirm. I have thought using Push Notification, but the problem is if the user disable this feature, the app will never receive this notification. Anyone know some direct communication server-app but keeping security?

Answer (score 1):

You may try the long polling technique. But it will drain your battery very fast, so be careful. The main idea is that you set connectionTimeout to a very very long time (30 mins for example) and when not closing that connection until the server says there is something. After receiving an answer or timeout, just reopen it.

Another approach is to make some method like `getJobStatus` on the server, assign a unique id for your job and ask the server if it's complete every N minutes for example.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to synchronise the client with the server, we usually need to combine both push and pull.

Something you can think of:

- The server provides an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) that allows the client to get the latest updates.
- On the client side, when the app is active, use a timer to try fetching updates every N minutes.
- When the app is in the background, use a background fetch to try fetching updates. In this case, the user doesn't care about if the task is done instantly, because his is not using it.
- Call the getUpdates when the app becomes active from the background, to make sure handle the updates when the user starts to use it.